# Does the Azure service bus client automatically use a retries for transient errors returned from the service bus?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

I have a very simple Azure function that uses an Http Trigger to send messages to an Azure Service Bus topic.  I want to retry this function if the service bus returns a transient error.  I have reviewed [the default policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.retryexponential?view=azure-dotnet), but I don't know how to verify if it will be used out of the box.  Do I need to add anything to my function code to ensure that such a retry policy will be used?

I also want to log messages that fail to be loaded onto the service bus after the retry policy fails.  Should I wrap the contents of the function in a try-catch block and perform the log in the catch statement?

```
[FunctionName("MessageLoader")]
[return: ServiceBus("%Topic_Name%", Connection = "Topic_Connection")]
public static async Task<TopicMessage> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = "domain/load-message")] HttpRequestMessage req)
{
    var stringRequestBody = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TopicMessage>(stringRequestBody);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in this case (Service Bus binding), the [default retry policy](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/ac4df9c40897463c5c0781bbeb0496547958ae75/sdk/servicebus/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/src/RetryPolicy.cs#L37) is used. You do not need to do anything special. To verify if it's working, you should see [failed dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies#tracing-from-requests-to-dependencies) in app insights whenever a call fails if you [integrated it correctly](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring).

To your second question, if it fails after the retry gives up, you do not need to log manually. You should see error logged in app insights automatically captured if you [integrated it correctly](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring).

If you want to log custom error on failure, you should use [Servicebus message sender by creating it yourself](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues#write-code-to-send-messages-to-the-queue) instead of Function output binding.

Comment: The problem is, I need to add custom information to my logs, so I need to write a line somewhere in my function like: _log.LogError("error: " + businessObject.custom_message);.  How can I add custom data to my logs in this case?  Or do I have to remove the output binding to do so?

Comment: In that case, you should use Servicebus message sender by creating it yourself instead of Function output binding.